# Apache Beam : WriteToBigQuery does not work if preceded by a stateful Transform unless re-windowing is applied

Tags: python, google-bigquery, streaming, apache-beam

I have a simple pipeline that does not work as expected, and any documentation I find does not explain its behaviour. In short, WriteToBigQuery in streaming mode fails if it is preceded by a stateful Transform, like GroupIntoBatches, unless global windows are re-applied before streaming it into BQ. Does anyone have a meaningful explanation?

This does work:

```
    result = (
        p
        | "Read Data"
            >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(
                subscription="projects/myproject/subscriptions/mysubscription",
                with_attributes=False,
            ).with_output_types(bytes)
        | "Decompose Data" >> beam.ParDo(DecomposeData())
        | "Window into Fixed Intervals"
                >> beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(self.window_size))
        | "Transform Data" >> beam.ParDo(TransformData())
        | "Write to BigQuery Table" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            table=_choose_table,
            schema=_choose_schema,
            create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND))
```

This fails:

```
    result = (
        p
        | "Read Data"
            >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(
                subscription="projects/myproject/subscriptions/mysubscription",
                with_attributes=False,
            ).with_output_types(bytes)
        | "Decompose Data" >> beam.ParDo(DecomposeData())
        | "Window into Fixed Intervals"
                >> beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(self.window_size))
        | "Add Dummy Key" >> beam.Map(lambda elem: (None, elem))
        | "Group into Batches"
            >> beam.GroupIntoBatches(
                max_buffering_duration_secs=self.window_size,
                batch_size=self.batch_size,
            )
        | "Discard Dummy Key" >> beam.MapTuple(lambda _, val: val)**
        | "Transform Data" >> beam.ParDo(TransformData())
        | "Write to BigQuery Table" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            table=_choose_table,
            schema=_choose_schema,
            create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND))
```

This works again:

```
    result = (
        p
        | "Read Data"
            >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(
                subscription="projects/myproject/subscriptions/mysubscription",
                with_attributes=False,
            ).with_output_types(bytes)
        | "Decompose Data" >> beam.ParDo(DecomposeData())
        | "Window into Fixed Intervals"
                >> beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(self.window_size))
        | "Add Dummy Key" >> beam.Map(lambda elem: (None, elem))
        | "Group into Batches"
            >> beam.GroupIntoBatches(
                max_buffering_duration_secs=self.window_size,
                batch_size=self.batch_size,
            )
        | "Discard Dummy Key" >> beam.MapTuple(lambda _, val: val)
        | "Transform Data" >> beam.ParDo(TransformData())
        | "Re-window" >> beam.WindowInto(window.GlobalWindows())
        | "Write to BigQuery Table" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            table=_choose_table,
            schema=_choose_schema,
            create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND))
```

Comment: How does the pipeline fail? Are there any accompanying error messages? I also see you mentioned elsewhere that you are using DirectRunner. Have you checked if the error occurs on any other runners?

Answer (score 0):

This is very weird as I am using the same approach, before `WriteToBigQuery` I am batching elements. This is what I have:

```
        tagged_events = (
            pcoll
            | "Key events" >> WithKeys(add_keys)
            | "With timestamps" >> ParDo(AddTimestamp())
            | "Window"
            >> WindowInto(
                windowfn=FixedWindows(self.window_interval_seconds),
                allowed_lateness=self.window_lateness_seconds,
            )
            | "Get latest elements per key" >> combiners.Latest.PerKey()
            | "Reshuffle elements" >> Reshuffle()
            | "Prepare for insertion" >> FlatMapTuple(prepare_for_insert)
            | "Tag Value" >> ParDo(TagTableValue()).with_outputs(*BQ_TABLES)
        )

        for table in BQ_TABLES:
            errors = (
                tagged_events[table]
                | f"Reshuffle to {table}" >> Reshuffle()
                | f"Batch  {table} elements"
                >> BatchElements(
                    min_batch_size=500, max_batch_size=500
                )
                | f"Flatten batch of {table}" >> FlatMap(flatten_list)
                | f"Write to {table}" >> WriteToBigQuery(
                    table=f"{self.project}:{self.dataset}.{table}",
                    create_disposition=BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_NEVER,
                    write_disposition=BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                    insert_retry_strategy=RetryStrategy.RETRY_NEVER,
                    ignore_insert_ids=True,
                    batch_size=BIGQUERY_INSERT_MAX_BATCH_SIZE,
                )
            )
```

One thing to note is that batching yields a batch, meaning a list of elements to be inserted, but the BigQuery sink expects single elements. That's why I have that Flatten step before insert.

Comment: Indeed, I have abbreviated the code but I do have a step where I also decompose a list into single lines before I feed them to BQ. Btw, even with BatchElements it does not work.

For completeness, this pipeline runs on DirectRunner, and I have to use Apache Beam 2.30rc1 to make part of it work (on 2.29 there are typecast errors related to BQ that pop up).

Comment: Hmm, I run this with 2.28 and haven't updated to 2.29 yet...

Comment: Small thing to add here, I did try to update to 2.29.0, but I faced some issues with BigQuery sink, it was a performance issue on my end. Google support engineers suggested waiting to 2.30.0 release and skip 2.29.0. So maybe try downgrading? Not sure Dataflow supports 2.30rc1 yet...